# What's the difference between $\equiv$ and $\leftrightarrow$ in a formal proof?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Some texts and online sources seem to imply that they're interchangeable, while others say that there is at least a small nuanced difference between the two.

For example, I've read that $ \equiv $ can be read as "can be replaced in a logical proof with...", yet I've also seen $ \leftrightarrow $ used in that same vein.

Edit:
I'm trying to write my own textbook on this material as a way of forcing me to learn as much as possible before my final in 3 weeks. I'm trying to figure out a way to describe what $ \equiv $ means, while I've described $ \leftrightarrow $ as "If and only if"

Comment: It means whatever your lecturer says it means.

Comment: As far as i've seen, they are equivalent and iff respectively. Mean the same but emphasis is different.

Comment: If $=$ means "equal", then $\equiv$ means "*really* equal, since it has one more horizontal bar. :-)

Comment: @coffeemath like $<<$ means *really smaller than* and $>>$ means *really larger than*? ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Between all things that are equal, some things equal more than others! :-)

Comment: Well, I could go $\leftrightarrow$ on that! (both ways).

Comment: @Asaf, well "all things being equal", I'll settle for that! :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In propositional calculus there is a **connective** $\rightarrow$ and often one for $\leftrightarrow$, which is a part of the formal language and how we create new propositions; and there is another form, $\implies$ and $\iff$ (also written as $\cong$) which are *meta*-statements.

Whereas $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$ is a **proposition**, $\varphi\iff\psi$ is a **statement about propositions**.

It is true, however, that $\varphi\iff\psi$ is true, if and only if $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$ is a tautology. However there is a difference between a proposition, and a statement about propositions; and I cannot stress this difference enough in this post.

Comment: Snow is white if and only if it is true that snow is white?

Comment: @Neal: Yes. Exactly. One is a predicate (being white) about a term (snow), the other is a claim *about* the term and the predicate.

Comment: @Neal The point is that in general some meta-statements cannot be expressed (or proved) inside a logic system, therefore we have to be very careful if we're "inside" or "outside" (at the meta- level).

Comment: Dear Asaf, would you mind taking a look at [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018091/using-implies-to-refer-to-material-conditional/3884866?noredirect=1#comment8226111_3884866)?

Answer (score 6):

With respect to the "$\equiv$" symbol (my comment was getting long!):

This is more in the way of speculation, but it seems that "$a \equiv b$" is used in some (not all) contexts to denote "$a$ is identically $b$", or in other contexts to convey that $a$ and $b$ are *essentially* equivalent (with respect to some equivalence-relation, e.g. congruence modulo $n$, or geometric congruence, or truth-functionality, or... etc.), again, depending on the contexts in which it's being used.

This would be consistent with the frequent use of the symbol "$\equiv$" in introductory logic texts to convey that $a \equiv b$ holds (is true) whenever $a$ and $b$ evaluate to the same truth value. It's also consistent with what you've read:  "$\equiv$" can be read as "can be replaced in a logical proof with...", in the sense that if "$p\equiv q$", then replacing every occurrence of $p$ with $q$ (or vice-versa) will not change the truth-value of any propositions thus impacted.

I know that I've used "$\equiv$" and "$\leftrightarrow$" interchangeably on this site, when answering, e.g., questions about propositional logic: partly for reasons related to trying to match the notation used in the question, and partly due to being careless and/or not necessarily knowing better.

Answer (score 3):

Some author as do use $\equiv$ to mean "if and only if". Another option, which I use from time to time, is to use $\equiv$ as a sort of equality symbol when I am talking about formulas. If I want to give the name $\phi$ to the formula "$a=b"$, I don't want to write
$$
\phi = a = b
$$
so I write
$$
\phi \equiv a = b
$$
instead. This allows me to avoid using quotation symbols.

This latter usage is not documented anywhere, I as far as I know. I am not aware of any book that describes it in detail. But I can explain my motivations for using it:

- I don't want to re-use the $=$ sign for another purpose; the first displayed formula is not appealing. But quotation marks in displayed formulas are also unappealing.
- When I write $\phi \equiv a = b$, I sometimes don't care if $\phi$ *is* the formula $a=b$ or is just equivalent to it. But for the rest of the proof I will act as if it is that formula. So the $\equiv$ symbol, which connotes "equivalent", suggests that all that matters in the beginning is that $\phi$ is equivalent to $a=b$.

Comment: Do you know of other authors that do this?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, unfortunately. I believe I picked it up form someone else at some point, but I can't say who or when.

Answer (score 0):

"$↔$" denotes an equivalent statement in formal logic.

e.g. $A^B ↔ B^A$ (because of the commutative properties).

While "$≡$" denotes an equivalent statement in a mathematical equation, but definition wise it means "identical to".

e.g. $3 \times 4 ≡ 4 \times 3$ (because of the commutative properties).

While like others said these can be interchangeable because they do mean the same thing you usually see "$↔$" in formal logic and "$≡$" in mathematical equations.

I should also note this perspective is from a CS major and may vary from a mathematical majors perspective, but this is what I was taught.

You may want to check [*Mathematical Structures for Computer Science* (2007) by Judith L. Gersting](http://books.google.com/books?id=lvAo3AeJikQC&pg=PA12&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q=%E2%89%A1&f=false) out. It is the book I am currently using for my Discrete Structures class.