# “$B$ does not follow from $A$” seems different from $\lnot(A\to B)$

Tags: logic

I am a beginner in logic. I have a basic question about implication. If "$B$ follows from $A$", we can write $A\rightarrow B$; but what about "$B$ does not follow from $A$"? Someone might suggest $\neg(A\rightarrow B)$, but that's not what "$B$ does not follow from $A$" means. Because $\neg(A\rightarrow B)$ is logically equal to $A\wedge\neg B$. But saying that "$B$ does not follow from $A$", it might be the case that $B$ is undecidable given $A$. So, I wonder how this sentence can be analyzed using logical tools. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $¬(A → B)$ is not intuitionistically equivalent to $A ∧ ¬B$. Perhaps your problem is that classical logic is too degenerate to express what you want.

Comment: @DanDoel Even though we don't have $(A\rightarrow B)\leftrightarrow(\neg A\vee B)$ in intuitionistic logic, we still can derive $\neg\neg A\wedge\neg B$ from $\neg(A\rightarrow B)$. In the wikipedia page for intuitionistic logic, it lists the valid rule $(\neg A\vee B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow B)$. Using contraposition, now derive $\neg(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\neg(\neg A\vee B)$ and the consequent is equivalently to $\neg\neg A\wedge \neg B$. This is a result as terrible as $A\wedge \neg B$ because it says that $A$ is not negatable and $\neg B$ is true.

Comment: Typically the symbol used for this is $\implies$ (code is ```\implies```) not $\to$.

Comment: I've used $A\not \implies B$ and I don't think anyone has ever called me on it.  Technically it logistically doesn't mean *anything* because we can have any of the four truth values of $A$ and of $B$ but I use is as a warning "this line of reasoning is not valid". .. I don't know in formal logic what the answer to you question, but if we are concerned with only formal logic, then why would anyone ever need to make such a statement?

Comment: Intuitionistic logic isn't the only way to organize a system with more distinctions between formulas than classical logic. If the inuitionistic meaning of $¬(A → B)$ is still unacceptable, then one can try to craft something that is acceptable. That isn't really possible if one doesn't recognize that classical logic is merely *a* way to work, not *the* way to work, though. It seems like what is desired in this case is a sort of meta-reasoning, which could possibly be incorporated with modalities.

Comment: In classical natural deduction anyway, they are are the same. To prove that $B$ does not follow from $A$, it seems to me that you must prove that $A \land \neg B$ or equivalently, that  $\neg (A \implies B)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 'follows from', you should not use the *material* implication $\to$, but rather the *logical* implication, for which you can use $\Rightarrow$ or $\vDash$

The difference is that $\to$ is the truth-functional operator you are familiar with, but the $\Rightarrow$ is a *meta-logical* symbol that claims some logical relationship between two statements.

$P \to Q$ is true in some world as long as it is not true in that world that $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.

$P \Rightarrow Q$ is true is it *impossible* for $P$ to be true and $Q$ to be false, i.e. that there is *no* world in which $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.

It is the latter that we typically mean by 'follows from': no matter what the circumstances are (i.e. no matter what world we're dealing with), if $P$ is true, then $Q$ will be true.

So, to say that $Q$ does not follow from $P$, we can write $P \not \Rightarrow Q$ ... but we can *not* write $\neg (P \Rightarrow Q)$, because then we are mixing up logic with meta-logic. We should simply say that 'it is not the case that $P \Rightarrow Q$.

And indeed, just because it is not the case that $P \Rightarrow Q$, does not mean anything about the truth-value of $P$ or $Q$ when evaluated in some particular world. Notably, it does not mean that $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. Moreover, if in some specific world $P$ is true, $Q$ can still be true or false. So these are all things you were looking for.

In sum, the $\Rightarrow$ (or $\vDash$) is what you should use when thinking about logical implication, rather than the $\to$.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a case where $P \not \Rightarrow Q$ but it is not the case that $\neg (P \Rightarrow Q)$? I'm not sure I understand the distinction you're making.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect  As I tried to say at the end, you should avoid writing $\neg (P \Rightarrow Q)$: now you are mixing up a logic symbol with a meta-logic symbol in one expression: do *not* do that! You should really just stick to "It is not the case that $P \Rightarrow Q$", or write $P \not \Rightarrow Q$

Answer (score 4):

$A \to B$ does *not* mean "$B$ follows from $A$". It means "either $A$ is false or $B$ is true in this particular situation". It does not make sense to say such a thing as "$A \to B$ is true" without specifying in which situation/model it is to have that truth value. To say that a $A \to B$ is false in a given situation is indeed logically equivalent to $A \land \neg B$ being true in that situation.

If what you want to say is "$B$ logically follows from $A$", then you're not talking about truth in a specific situation, but preservance of truth  from the premises to the conclusion across *any* possible situation. In that case, what you really want is logical consequence, $\vDash$:

> $A \vDash B$
> = "In every situation in which $A$ is true, $B$ is true as well."

This permits for situations in which $B$ is false, as long as in those situations $A$ is false as well. It also permits for situations in which $B$ is true despite $A$ being false. What it rules out is the existence of situations in which $A$ is true but $B$ is false.

The negation of this is "$B$ does not follow from $A$":

> $A \not \vDash B$
> = "Not in every situation in which $A$ is true, $B$ is true as well."

This does not rule out the existence of situations in which $B$ is true or  $A$ false or both of that, but it does assert the existence of at least one situation in which $A$ is true but $B$ is not. It also permits for, but does not entail, the possibility that $B$ is false not only in some but all situation in which $A$ is true.

If you want to say that $B$ is *undecidable* from $A$, i.e. that there exist situations in which $A$ is true and $B$ false but there also exist situations in which $A$ is true and $B$ true, you have to make two claims:

> $A \not \vDash B$ and $A \not \vDash \neg B$

meaning that from $A$ you can neither definitely conclude $B$ nor $\neg B$.

---

We do have the following connection between the notions of material conditional and logical consequence (called the deduction theorem):

$$A \vDash B \text{ if and only if } \vDash A \to B$$

i.e. $B$ logically follows from $A$ iff the material conditional is $A \to B$ is tautological.
The crucial point here is that logical consequence commits the material conditional to being true in all situations; when the consequence is denied, $\not \vDash A \to B$, this merely negates its universalness, leading to the conditional being false in *some* situations -- which should be what you want. This is different from $\vDash \neg (A \to B)$, which would be a stronger claim meaning that $A \to B$ is false and thereby $A \land \neg B$ true in *all* situations, which, as you figured out, is not the intended state of affairs.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be propositions, the claim that $B$ doesn't follow from $A$ can be alternatively described as: either (i) $A$ implies $\neg B$ or (ii) $B$ is irrelevant to $A$ (i.e., given $A$, whether $B$ is true or not is not determined).

(i) can be easily expressed as (using your notation): $A\rightarrow\neg B$.

(ii) can hardly be expressed in the object language of formal logic. In order to express it, first define $p$ as a mapping from a proposition to a scale of probability ranging from 0 to 1, both ends included:
$$p:\textsf{Prop}\rightarrow[0,1].$$
So, the probability of $A$ and $B$ shall be expressed as $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ respectively. Now, consider (ii), it amounts to say that the probability of $B$ given $A$ is equal to the probability of $B$ itself but is irrelevant to the probability of $A$:
$$P(B|A)=P(B).$$
This might seem a little bit complicated, but I think it's the easiest way to capture (ii).

Comment: "$B$ does not follow from $A$" does *not* mean that $\neg B$ follows from $A$.

Comment: @lemontree You are right. But i was using the terminology that Samual used in his post. Now I make it more explicit: $A$ implies $\neg B$.

Comment: Yes, and precisely this is *not* a proper interpretation of the intended assertion. Your claim that "'$B$ does not follow from $A$' can alternatively be described as '$A$ implies $\neg B$' is misleading.

Comment: Your second claim that "$B$ is independent of $A$" can not be expressed in symbolic logic is also wrong -- it can be expressed via $\not \vDash$.

Comment: @lemontree Note that this is only the first clause in (i). I also give the second clause in (ii), which is exactly what Samuel means.

Comment: @lemontree Note that $\nvDash$ is a meta-level symbol. It's the negation of a judgment, but not a propositional level operator.

Comment: My point was that your answer reads (to me) as if (i) was one valid way to interpret "does not follow", and that's misleading.

Comment: Re. Meta symbol: Yes, I am aware. But it nevertheless is a formal symbol expressing exactly the desired statement, so again, your claim that "it can hardly be expressed in formal logic" is misleading.

Comment: @lemontree I've just read your discussion. It's very interesting. But I have the same doubt: can $\nvDash$ be interpreted propositionally? Because I will have to code it using proof assistant but I am unaware how meta symbols can be incorporated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. As you correctly note, it is a meta symbol and not a connective, i.e. not a symbol that *yields* an object-language proposition, but it is a symbol *operating* on propositions to produce a meta statement. Simply put, while connectives such as $\land$ and $\to$ are of type `prop -> prop -> prop`, $\vDash$ and $\not \vDash$ are of type `prop -> prop -> bool`. How these different levels would be incorporated of course depends entirely on the details of your implementation.

Comment: @lemontree When you say that $\vDash$ and $\nvDash$ are of type $\textsf{prop}\rightarrow\textsf{prop}\rightarrow\textsf{bool}$, I can see that it's equivalent to a valuation function $v$ such that $v(P)\in\{0,1\}$. Is this what you mean? But in that case, are you going to assign $0$ to $v(P)$ if $\nvDash P$? But that's again a strong result because as long as $v(P)$ is assigned $0$, it is equivalent to $\vDash\neg P$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's a compilcation: Conflating these two is what one doesn't want, and it makes sense to distinguish between $\{0, 1\}$ (call it `truthval` perhaps) as the truth value of a formlua assigned by a valuation vs. $\{True, False\}$ (what I meant by `bool`) as the judgement of a meta statement such as "... is tautological" or "... follows from ...". But this discussion really exceeds the scope of a comment thread; if you have more questions, I suggest you start a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at *modal logic*, which adds a new operator: $\square p$ means “$p$ is **necessarily** true”.  The idea is that we can imagine alternate worlds which are plausible, but different from the world in which we find ourselves.  For example, we find ourselves in a universe in which I am wearing a green shirt.  Is the necessarily the case?  No, of course not, we could easily have been in a universe in which I was wearing a blue shirt.  But could we have found ourselves in a universe in which $2+2=5$?  No, that is impossible; $2+2=4$ in every possible universe.  “I am wearing a green shirt” is only *locally* true, but $2+2=4$ is *globally* true.

The exact behavior and semantics of $\square$ is a philosophical question, and there are different ways to define it, just like the way it is a philosophical question  whether $p\to q$ is identical with $\lnot(p\land \lnot q)$.  (Classical logic says yes, intuitionistic logic says they are different.) One typical axiom is $\square p\to p$, which says that if $p$ is true in every possible universe, it is true in the particular universe in which we live. Another is $$\square(p\to q) \to (\square p\to \square q).$$

Here $\square(p\to q)$ means that $q$ *necessarily* follows from $p$:  in every possible universe where $p$ is true, $q$ is true in that universe also.

Suppose we agree that $\square p\to p$, so by contrapositive $\lnot p\to\lnot \square p$.  This says that if $p$ is false (in our universe), then it is not *necessarily* true.  But it might still be true in some other universe. We cannot conclude from $\lnot\square p$ ($p$ is not necessarily true) that $\square\lnot p$ ($p$ is necessarily false).

Now what you asked for is available: in modal logic, $\square(a\to b)$ means that $b$ necessarily follows from $a$, and $\lnot\square(a\to b)$ means that $b$ does not necessarily follow from $a$—but it might follow anyway, locally if not globally. Modal logic usually has a second operator $\diamond p$ which means that $p$ is *possibly* true; usually $\diamond p$ is taking to be an abbreviation for $\lnot\square\lnot p$, so that $\lnot\diamond p$ and $\square\lnot p$ are two ways of writing that $p$ is impossible.  So consider:

$$\square(p\to q)\\\\
p\to q\\\\
\diamond(p\to q)\\\\
$$

The first one says that from $p$ we can deduce $q$ in every possible universe.  The second only says that from $p$ we can deduce $q$ in the contingent universe we are actually in.  The last one only says that there is *some* universe, not necessarily this one, in which we can deduce $q$ from $p$.  Applying some simple transformations to the last one we can turn it into $$\lnot\square(p\land\lnot q)$$ which says that it is not necessarily the case that $p$ is true and $q$ is false.

[Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on modal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/)
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic)

Answer (score 0):

$A\; \implies \; B $ says that if $ A $ is true, we are sure and certain that $ B $ is true and cannot be false.

$ A $ does not imply $ B $ says that even if $ A $ is true, we can say Nothing about $ B $.

For example,
$(p\vee q)\wedge q $ does not imply $ p$.

$ p $ could true and false as well.

The best way to understand the "implication" begins by the notion of "Argument".

Comment: But your answer does not solve Samuel's question because he exactly knows what you have said and asks how the second line of your answer can be formally analyzed. I think that's what he wants. Not just an example, but a general way to formalize that.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases of trying to say "it doesn't follow that...." the issue is that there is implicit quantification that needs to be negated.  For example, let $S$ be "it is (S)aturday" and $W$ be "it is the (W)eekend".  From $S$ follows $W$, so we can say $$S \to W$$
But just because it is the weekend doesn't mean it is Saturday.  But as you identified, $\lnot(W \to S)$ doesn't say what we want** because it is propositionally equivalent to $W \land \lnot S$. What is missing is that your full statement is "for every day, if it is the weekend then it is Saturday", which is correct to negate as "there is a day which is a weekend but is not Saturday":

$$\lnot \forall d. W(d) \to S(d)$$
$$\exists d. W(d) \land \lnot S(d)$$

---

** Except sometimes it does, because you could have meant for example "if today is the weekend then today is Saturday" because you have ruled out that it isn't Sunday.  In this case $\lnot (W \to S)$ is correct.