# Is $\curvearrowright$ a valid symbol for "implies that"?

Tags: logic, notation

I learned in high school from my favorite math teacher (who also has a PhD in mathematics) that the $\curvearrowright$ symbol means "implies that" (in German "daraus folgt"; "from that follows").

Now that I am learning higher math elsewhere I have not found this notation anywhere; it always seems to be the $\Rightarrow$ symbol.

The $\curvearrowright$ symbol has really grown on me, and it takes much less time to draw than the commonly used $\Rightarrow$ symbol.

I am just curious if $\curvearrowright$ is also a commonly accepted symbol? Maybe it's an old DDR (communist Germany) thing - as that's where my teacher received his PhD?

Comment: Is it possible your teacher meant the symbol $\supset$? Apparently both $\implies$ and $\supset$ represent material implications (though I have never seen the latter used in this instance).

Comment: I have never seen that symbol used that way before.

Comment: I use $\implies$ (`\implies` latex command).

Comment: I have also seen it as a bilinear product $x \curvearrowright y$ of a $K$-algebra, actually rooted trees algebras. But as an implication only informally (unofficially).

Comment: @Kman3 no, I have had him for many years and I am 100% sure it's ↷

Comment: does it have to be curved? I use $\rightarrow$ all the time

Comment: It's not standard notation, so I'd discourage using it. Just use $\rightarrow$ which is one of the standard notations for material implication (and quicker to draw too than $\implies$)

Comment: along with the example of @DietrichBurde, another slight word of warning: $\curvearrowright$ is also used occasionally to denote *group actions*; ie one writes $G\curvearrowright X$ to mean that a group $G$ acts on a set $X$.

Comment: @user3187119 If my answer has helped you, I'd appreciate a checkmark :)

Comment: Unforunately not, I've seen the Wikipedia page but haven't seen any additional/historical information around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example: [This script](https://users.fmi.uni-jena.de/%7Eharoske/ha-1/ha-1_2.pdf)* by the german professor [Dorothee Haroske](https://users.fmi.uni-jena.de/%7Eharoske/)  uses your symbol all the time.

---

* Which I, funnily, looked for just a few days ago because I was searching for a reference of the density of the set of all compactly supported smooth functions in the set of all $L^p(\mathbb R)$ functions, $p\in[1,\infty[$)

Comment: Very interesting! My teacher was also from Jena, and also studied and got his PhD at the Friedrich Schiller University Jena! Maybe it's a "Jena thing"?

Answer (score 8):

The commonly accepted symbols for implications are $\Rightarrow$ and its variation $\Longrightarrow$.

Objectively seen, it does not take much less time to draw $\curvearrowright$ than the commonly used $\Rightarrow$ symbol. The former one uses $15$ and the latter one $10$ letters in MathJax code. Also drawing it on paper does not make a real difference since a short line can be drawn in less than a second.

The only source I could find was in the German Wikipedia article, called "[Folgepfeil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folgepfeil#Textverarbeitung_und_Satz)" (implication arrow):

> In TeX werden sie als \Leftarrow und \Rightarrow und \Leftrightarrow (mit dem Großbuchstaben in ausdrücklicher Unterscheidung zum einfachen Pfeil) beziehungsweise \nLeftarrow, \nRightarrow, \nLeftrightarrow (mit vorangestelltem kleinen „n“ für Negation) gesetzt. **Auch hier gibt es etliche Varianten:**

Then a long table of variations of the implication arrow follows, including $\curvearrowleft$ and $\curvearrowright$.

It is understandable that $\curvearrowright$ has a somewhat personal meaning to you, but I would refrain from using it. The curved arrow is not a commonly used symbol to denote an implication and therefore the usage of this symbol may lead to uncertainty of the reader.

Comment: @user3187119 I'm under the impression that the OP is referring to symbols for implication (meta-symbols), [rather than](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813) symbols for *material* implication. Implication is almost universally symbolised as $\implies,$ while as you pointed out, material implication doesn't seem to have a universally-agreed on symbol (I prefer $\rightarrow$).

Comment: @RyanG Thanks for noticing. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I think he may have had something different in mind: imagine that you derive that $x + 1 > 0$ (to take a simple example). From that it follows that $x > -1$.

You sometimes see this written (incorrectly) as

$$x + 1 > 0\ \Rightarrow\ x > -1$$

which is a correct statement, but it doesn't tell you anything about $x$, in the sense that it is still correct when $x = -2$.

If instead of that you write something like

$$x + 1 > 0\ \curvearrowright\ x > -1$$

at the very least you don't write something that has a strictly defined and different meaning, and it is natural to read this as "it follows that" or "hence". I often use $\leadsto$ myself, not sure where I picked that up, but probably during my studies.

In short, $\Rightarrow$ is "implies" and $\curvearrowright$ would be "it follows that".

Comment: Yes, that's how he used it!