# Propositional Logic Question Related to Understanding "→" and Tautologies

Tags: logic

I should preface this with that I have never studied logic before. When answering my question, please assume that I know nothing about formal logic.

Just now, I was reading a different question and one of answers gave the statement:

$(A⇒B)⇔(¬B⇒¬A)$

(Colloquially known as: the statements "Paris is in France" and "Not being in France means not being in Paris" mutually imply each other.)

Initially, I got confused and understood $(A⇒B)⇒(¬B⇒¬A)$, but not $(¬B⇒¬A)⇒(A⇒B)$.

Then I realized I was mistakenly thinking of the "$⇒$" in $(¬B⇒¬A)$ as an "$∧$", in which case $(¬B∧¬A)⇏(A⇒B)$.

However, this simple issue raised another more fundamental question in my mind:

What is propositional logic assuming in such a statement for $(¬Q⇒¬P)⇒(P⇒Q)$ to always be True?

Can't there be a case, where $¬P$ is a tautology, in other words, $(¬Q⇒¬P)∧(Q⇒¬P)$, and thus in this case, $(¬Q⇒¬P)⇏(P⇒Q)$?

This would be assuming that, in a case where $⊨P$ ("$P$ is a tautology"), that $Q⇒P$ is True. **In this case, isn't the above a contradiction? What I'm I confusing here?**

Conversely, if I assume that in a case where, $⊨P$, that $Q⇒P$ is False, this would seem to suggest that "$⇒$" would denote more than simply the truth value of a proposition. Since, $Q⇒P$ would be False even though $P$ is always True when $Q$ is True, which I now understand would be blatantly wrong.

---

(My question can be boiled down to simply not distinctly understanding what the $→$ logical operator does, i.e. in terms of its truth table where, only the proposition $True→False$ is False, and the propositions, $True→True$, $False→True$, and $False→False$, are all True. This is evidently a common confusion among laymen and new students alike, since it's non-intuitive to consider what "if... then..." (or even worse, "implies") means in the context of $False→True$ and $False→False$ propositions (i.e. propositions with a False antecedent), when a proposition can only be evaluated as True or False.)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Updated the title and added a linguistic explanation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $A$ simply doesn't exist? How can the statement "You are in France" not exist? It's a statement -- I just stated it -- so of course it exists, though it might be false. Do you mean that the statement is always false--that is, there does not exist any possible world in which $A$ is true?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, where the condition $¬A$ is always true. The linguistic statement I gave was a very poor example relative to my question, it's just the one that's often used to explain contrapositives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" *Can't there be a case, where $¬P$ is a tautology, in other words, $(¬Q⇒¬P)∧(Q⇒¬P)$, and thus in this case, $(¬Q⇒¬P)⇏(P⇒Q)$?* "

In propositional logic, a tautology is a proposition that is true **by virtue of its truth-functional form**. As such, $¬P$ is patently not a tautology, merely that it is (*being interpreted as*) true, i.e., that it is a true statement. [In other words, we distinguish the claim “$\lnot P$ is always true (*whichever the truth value of $Q$*)” from the claim “$\lnot P$ is always true (*in truth-functional form*)”.]

So, since $¬P$ is true (and $P$ thus false), the [meta-statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813) $$(¬Q\rightarrow ¬P)⇏(P\rightarrow Q)\tag1$$ has both a true antecedent and a true consequent (since both $x\rightarrow T\;$ and $\;F\rightarrow x$ are by definition true). As such, and since $T\rightarrow T$ is by definition true, it must be that $$(¬Q\rightarrow ¬P)⇒(P\rightarrow Q),$$ i.e., statement (1) is false.

Comment: Thank you. It took a couple of readings and a quick Google search, but between your answer and sundowner's answer, I believe I understand where I misunderstood what these statements meant.

Comment: @Gnosis i added a line, even though you most likely don't need the clarification by now

Answer (score 2):

In propositional logic, if $Q$ is a theorem, then so is $P\to Q$, for any choice of $P$. It helps to think of "$P\to Q$" as saying "knowing that $P$ is true is sufficient to know that $Q$ is true". It's not saying anything about whether $P$ "causes" $Q$, it's just describing the pairs of truth values that we consider possible. We think of each proposition as a fully-qualified sentence about the world, so no proposition is fundamentally "conditionally true" or true "because of" another proposition; each one is just either a true statement about the world or a false one.

First-order logic (propositional logic with variables and [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))) is a little more expressive: you can have $P(t)\to Q(t)$ be true for a particular term $t$ while the "for all" sentence $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$ is false. In this case, you might think of the former sentence as an "accidental" implication and the latter as stating more of a "real" one. (But note that $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))$ is derivable from $\forall xQ(x)$, so it can still be "accidentally true".)

You might also be interested in [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic), which formalizes the notions of "necessary" and "possible" propositions.

Comment: Thank you. This is more along the lines of the kind of explanation I was looking for, although it does not address my question directly as far as I can tell. Unfortunately, I know even less about first-order logic to properly understand your second paragraph.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to edit to address your question more directly. For now, does it help to read $P$ as $\lnot B$ and $Q$ as $\lnot A$? It seems to me that your question is not so much about negation as it is about interpreting the $\to$ symbol.

Comment: Your emphasis on "logically imply" and "logical conditions" makes it sound like you want to think of implication as a sort of fundamental metaphysical relationship linking two propositions. But propositional logic is arguably not about such relationships - the $\to$ sentence just rules out a particular assignment of truth values.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right that my question is about understanding implication (→) rather than about "negation". It just so happened that the statement I was thinking about which triggered this question happened to be a contrapositive statement. I edited the question title to reflect this.

Comment: To answer your second comment, I was thinking about propositional logic statements loosely/informally in terms of sets. i.e. $(A⇒B)$ is similar to saying that $A$ is either a subset of $B$ or simply is $B$.

Comment: I'm also trying to understand implication in the context of Tautologies. Specifically, if $P$ being a tautology (unconditionally true) implies that "no $Q$ can imply $P$", or that "every $Q$ implies $P$". Or if the statement can't be evaluated at all in the context of propositional logic.

Comment: Do the statements $⊨P$ and $⊤(P)$ mean something different when denoting a tautology? Wikipedia says that $⊨P$ denotes $P$ is "a semantic consequence of the empty set".

Comment: I've understood what you meant by "propositional logic is arguably not about such relationships - the → sentence just rules out a particular assignment of truth values", and also clarified my question considerably. It should be easier to tell what I'm trying to ask now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are too much biased for 'imply' in a natural language to interpret $\Rightarrow$.

In propositional logic, $P \Rightarrow Q$ is false only when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. And as noted in your question $P\Rightarrow Q$ is true if $Q$ is true. This is the definition.

So for example,

- 'Berlin is in France' $\Rightarrow$ 'Paris is in France'
- $1 = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $2+2=4$

are both true in terms of propositional logic because Paris is in France and $2+2=4$, however weird these sound.

Regarding your question, $(Q\Rightarrow \neg P) \land (\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P)$ can be true if $\neg P$ is a tautology, as you say. But that does not entails $(\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P)\not\Rightarrow (P\Rightarrow Q)$.

In order to 'prove' that $(\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P)\not\Rightarrow (P\Rightarrow Q)$ can happen, you need to find a case where $\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$ is true and $P\Rightarrow Q$ is false. (Here $\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P$ replaces $P$ and $P\Rightarrow Q$ replaces $Q$ in the first sentence of the 2nd paragraph above, the definition of $\Rightarrow$).

But this cannot happen: $P\Rightarrow Q$ is false means that $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, that is $\neg Q$ is true.Then, since $\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P$ is true, $\neg P$ is also true. Then we have both $P$ and $\neg P$ true, a contradiction.

I hope this helps you understand where you are confused, but probably you should check any standard textbook first. It will explain the same thing as above more properly. (I find the words above too clumsy...)

Comment: Thank you, between a bit of additional reading, your answer, and Ryan G's answer below, I believe I understand where my misunderstanding was.

Answer (score 1):

The formal way to prove this kinds of statements , is to compare for each A,B, that the result is the same.
You can easily verify that these two are just the same.

Comment: I'm asking the question from a stand-point of trying to understand propositional logic, not from a practical stand-point.

Comment: It's practical :) when would you say that two logic statements are equal?