# Verify that $(\neg P\land N)\lor(\neg D \land P)\rightarrow \neg D\lor N$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The answer seems to be $\neg D \lor N$, but below is what I got,no idea where it goes wrong

$$\begin{aligned} (\neg P\land N)\lor(\neg D \land P) &\equiv \neg(\neg N\lor P)\lor \neg(\neg P\lor D)\\ &\equiv\neg[(N\implies P)\land(P\implies D)]\\&\rightarrow \neg(N\implies D)\\ &\equiv\neg(\neg N\lor D) \\ &\equiv\neg D\land N \end{aligned}
$$

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: The third $\equiv$ is only a $\to$...

Comment: Did you checked it with truth table?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is it right after edited? this is draw from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4361214/how-to-show-negd-land-p-land-n-lor-p-implies-neg-d-lor-n-by-propositio

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your reply. What he said is $\neg D\lor N$, but what I got is $\neg D\land N\,$  I have no idea where it goes wrong in my algebraic operation

Comment: Please, check it with truth assignment: $v(N)=T$ and $v(D)=T$.

Comment: But the ERROR is the same...

Comment: I have no idea about what you said. much appreciate if you can let me know what my process is wrong that I get $\neg D\land N$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you for your reply. I've never seen this inference, but this seems to analogise to *all elements in two sets intersection must also in their union*

Comment: @LJNG No it’s still not right. The implication to $\lnot D\land N$ is invalid. If N is true, P is false and D is true, the premise is true and the conclusion is false.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you for your reply. where is my deduce process gone wrong?

Comment: @LJNG The third inference… the implication. (It would be valid in the opposite direction that you used it.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I don't think I get you, would you please leave your answer rather than comments. Cheers

Comment: @LJNG No, I only have a phone right now and don’t have time to type it out. My advice would be to take the truth values for N, D, and P I mentioned above and check at which step the expression’s truth value switches from true to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \begin{aligned} (\neg P\land N)\lor(\neg D \land P) &\equiv \neg(\neg N\lor P)\lor \neg(\neg P\lor D)\\ &\equiv\neg((N\implies P)\land(P\implies D))\\&\rightarrow \neg(N\implies D)\\ &\equiv\neg(\neg N\lor D) \\ &\equiv\neg D\land N \end{aligned}

That logical entailment in Line 3 is incorrect, as evidenced by the assignment $(P,N,D)=(0,1,1).$

Here's a correct attempt, if you don't mind applying the distributive laws: \begin{aligned} (\neg P\land N)\lor(\neg D \land P) &\equiv (¬P∨¬D)∧(¬P∨P)∧(N∨¬D)∧(N∨P)\\
&\models (N∨¬D)\\
&\equiv \neg D ∨ N. \end{aligned} Thus, $$(\neg P\land N)\lor(\neg D \land P) \to \neg D ∨ N$$ is a validity, as required.

P.S. I use $≡$ and $⊨$ to mean logically equivalent and [logically implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251001/21813), respectively (i.e., as metalogical symbols), while I use $\to$ merely as the material conditional (i.e., as a logical operator). As for $\implies,$ I use it just to mean [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813) (e.g., $x=2\implies x^2=4$) rather than as the material conditional.

Comment: I think you misunderstand their attempt (the third line’s indentation is misleading… it is supposed to be a new line which is implied by the previous line, not a continuation of the sentence on the second line.) (Now I see it’s actually explicitly that way now, since someone edited it with the same reading you had.)

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah, haha, thanks for the observation and fixing the Question post; I've edited my answer, in response.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to verify the relationship using Natural Deduction:

$
\dfrac
{
((\neg p\land n) \vee (\neg d \land p))
\quad
\dfrac{\dfrac{[(\neg p \land n)]}{n}(\land E)}{(\neg d \lor n)}(\lor I)
\quad
\dfrac{\dfrac{[(\neg d \land p)]}{(\neg d)}(\land E)}{(\neg d \lor n)}(\lor I)
}
{
(\neg d \lor n)
}(\lor E)
$

PS: This is my second answer. The first one, as pointed out by
spaceisdarkgreen, was completely wrong.