# What can we infer about an argument's validity given the following information?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

> 1. Suppose the conclusion of an argument is a tautology. What can you conclude about the validity of the argument?

My answer: **Valid**, because this argument is impossible to have true premises and false conclusion.

> 2. What if the conclusion is a contradiction?

My answer: **Invalid** when an argument is possible to have true premises and false conclusion; otherwise, **Valid**.

> 3. What if one of the premises is either a tautology or a contradiction?

My answer: **Invalid** when an argument is possible to have true premises and false conclusion; otherwise, **Valid**. (It is the form that makes arguments valid. Plus we could asume a premise were true even this premise is a contradiction.)

---

**ADDENDUM 1** to add my new answers after reading the accepted answer

> 1. Suppose the conclusion of an argument is a tautology. What can you conclude about the validity of the argument?

My new answer: **Valid**. Because $\forall$x C(x), it is impossible to have $\exists$x[ $\forall$y P(x,y) $\land$ $\neg$ C(x) ].

> 2. What if the conclusion is a contradiction?

My new answer:It depends on the premises.

**Valid** when $\forall$x [$\forall$yP(x,y) $\to$ C(x)]

**Invalid** when $\exists$x[ $\forall$y P(x,y) $\land$ $\neg$ C(x) ]

> 3. What if one of the premises is either a tautology or a contradiction?

My new answer:

**Valid** when $\forall$x [$\forall$yP(x,y) $\to$ C(x)]

**Invalid** when $\exists$x[ $\forall$y P(x,y) $\land$ $\neg$ C(x) ]

---

**ADDENDUM 2**

`Valid`

> $\forall$x [$\forall$yP(x,y) $\to$ C(x)]

`Invalid`

**meaning**: Negate the above formula

> $\neg$ { $\forall$x [$\forall$yP(x,y) $\to$ C(x)] }

$\iff$

> $\exists$x[ $\forall$y P(x,y) $\land$ $\neg$ C(x) ]

x $\in$ {1,...,$\mathrm{2}^{n}$}

y $\in$ {1,...,n}

P(x, y) A premise in (x,y) enty of the truth table.

C(x) The conclusion in the row x of the truth table.

Comment: Do you mean Example3.e.?

Comment: Do you mean Example1?

Comment: Rules: 1) a tautology follows from **every** premise. 2) from a contradiction **everything** follows.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't follow that. I read similar aritcles you write about.

Comment: Also, why provide several examples one one suffices your post is unnecessarily long…

Comment: I am confused by this exercise and I spend a long day surfing the internet. Try to find some answer which is easily understood.

Comment: Rule 1) a tautology is **always** True; thus if we have a tautology $\top T$ as conclusion, whatever proposition $P$ we use as premise we have that $P ∴ \top$ is *valid* because in every case where $P$ is True also $\top$ is.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you mean the cases when premises are tautologies or contradictions?

Comment: Rule 2) a contradiction is always False; thus if we have a contradiction $\bot$ as conclusion, whatever proposition $P$ we use as premise we have that $P∴\bot$ can be valid in only one case: when $P$ is never True, i.e. when it is a contradiction. In this case, when the premises is a contradiction $\bot$, we have that $\bot ∴ Q$ holds for a proposition $Q$ whatever.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "only one case: when P is never True, i.e. when it is a contradiction." But how about two or more premises?

Comment: In this case we consider a set $\Gamma$ of premises; we have that $\Gamma ∴ \bot$ holds only when $\Gamma$ is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. it includes a contradiction. Simple example with $\{ P, \lnot P \}$ as $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 1. Suppose the conclusion of an argument is a tautology. What can you conclude about the validity of the argument?

Every conditional with a tautological consequent is a logical validity.

In other words, every argument with a tautological conclusion is valid.

> > 2. What if the conclusion is a contradiction?

A conditional with a contradiction as consequent is a logical validity precisely when its antecedent is unsatisfiable.

In other words, an argument with a contradiction as conclusion is valid precisely when its premises are inconsistent.

> > 3a. What if one of the premises is a tautology?

A conjunction's truth value is not altered by eliminating one of its tautological conjuncts; therefore, a tautological premise confers no information about the argument's validity.

> > 3b. What if one of the premises is a contradiction?

Every conjunction with a contradiction as conjunct is a contradiction; therefore, every argument with a contradiction as one of its premises is valid.

Comment: Appreciate it. The wordinig is quite readable and understood easily.

Comment: The difficulty I face is that although the core of the concept is the same, but different people or article use different wording or terminology to compose sentences to convey the concept. sigh

Comment: @StatsCruncher [Indeed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4455119/still-not-getting-difference-bettwen-implies-and-entails-and-the-role-of-interp#comment9331939_4455130)

Comment: You have open mindset to accept different users. Even some users like me can't clarify questions clearly at first. But users like you remind me of Federico Ardila-Mantilla's axioms. So I mentions Diversity and I guess that you accept different users who study mathematics even they face various learning difficulties.

Comment: @StatsCruncher Thanks for your kind words. -)

Comment: Many users here like you deserve it. Definitely!